# Can I send extra data to Cybersource Secure Acceptance for use after a successful payment?

Tags: php, mobile, cybersource

I'm trying to integrate Cybersource Secure Acceptance into a mobile app I'm building. Only problem is, I need to a way to pass extra data to the php that Cybersource supplies without the users entering, i.e: first name, last name, email, card number (not to save of course) and just have users review their order in a webview. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, custom data fields are supported by CyberSource APIs. I would suggest you look at the guides relevant to your implementation. Start at https://support.cybersource.com/ and https://developer.cybersource.com/ to find the guides.

As a sample, however, if you're using the Simple Order API you can use the below fields to send data to CyberSource that will be returned to you in the reply. NOTE that Personally Identifiable Information is prohibited in these fields.

```
merchantDefinedData_field1
merchantDefinedData_field2
merchantDefinedData_field3
merchantDefinedData_field4
```

For data such as name, email address, etc that you already have stored and don't want the user to re-enter, this data can be POST'ed to the APIs via hidden input fields. Naturally, the field names must correspond to the API's required field names.